# How to pass 2 parameters to a GET request using retrofit?

Tags: android, node.js, mongodb, express, retrofit

The normal `GET` request doesn't have any arguments, right? It just fetches the whole data. The thing is: I need to fetch the Salons that are closer to a given coordinate point (lat/lng) and that's why I need to pass 2 parameters to the `GET` request ( `express js` ).

I'm using **NODE JS**, **EXPRESS JS**, **MONGO DB**.
In frontend, I'm using **Android Studio** and coding with **KOTLIN**.

The following code is the interface (frontend/kotlin):

```html
    @GET("/salao")
    fun getAllSaloes(@Query("lat") lat: Float,
                     @Query("lon") lon: Float): Call<salaoList>
```

and the following code is the backend code (express js):

```js
    app.get('/salao/:lat/:lon', (req,res) => {
      var lat = req.params.lat;
      var lon = req.params.lon;

      Salao.find({
        "loc": {
            $near: {
              $geometry: {
                 type: "Point",
                 coordinates: [ lat, lon ] // Latitude - Longitude

              },
            }
          }
      }).then((saloes) => {
          console.log("Getting the closer salons...");
          res.send({saloes})
      },(e) => {
          res.status(400).send(e);
      });
    });
```

One important point: If I do not pass any parameter and only do a normal query and use lat-lng hardcoded (ex: -44.41241, -22.412412) it works.

The problem is on passing 2 parameters.

How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: In Android (Java/Kotlin) you are passing data directly to method method `getAllSaloes(-44.41241, -22.412412)`. Or I don't understand problem/question.

Comment: The normal GET request doesn't have any arguments, right? It just fetch the whole data. The thing is: I need to fetch the Salons that are closer to a given coordinate point (lat/lon) and that's why I need to pass 2 parameters to the GET request ( express js ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to send data in path like this:

```
 @GET("/salao/{lat}/{lng}")
Call<Response> getAllSaloes(@Path("lat") Long lat, @Path("lng") Long lng);
```

This will send data in form of /salao/123.21/2323

Comment: Worked... **tks**